# Poking around/debugging in IRB. Monkey-patch a method, then "undo" that change, without quitting IRB?

Tags: ruby, debugging, irb, monkeypatching

I find IRB extremely useful as a tool for trial and error style debugging, where I don't really know where a problem is coming from, but can take advantage of the REPL nature of IRB to quickly iterate through a list of potential ways to reproduce an issue and distill it down.

Occasionally I decide to re-open a class belonging to a loaded gem and add some debug output to a method, or override the method entirely.  Once that is done, is there an easy to way "un-monkey patch" the class, without quitting IRB and restarting it (my current approach)?

Comment: Sometimes by doing a load 'path/to/file.rb' the change will be reverted. But if the gem already does some monkey patching, then you'll need to restart `irb`, as otherwise it might monkeypatch your changes, rather than the original implementation.

Comment: If I used alias_method or something like that, instead of overriding the actual method, I wonder if it's easy enough to just "unalias" the method.

Comment: I think that feature is in ruby 2. I **really** think is a must, specially with so many frameworks adding /overriding methods on Kernel, Module and Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're redefining a method, you could create and `alias` for the old method and then define your new one. When you're done, you could redefine the method yet again and call the method alias.

Step one:

```
alias :old_method :method

def method
  # fancy new stuff
end
```

When you're done:

```
def method
  old_method
end
```

Comment: Hah, I had just commented this on the original question as my mind was running wild, then saw you'd posted exactly the same thing!  This seems exactly like the sort of thing I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of redefining you can "re-alias" `alias :method :old_method` (and `remove_method(:old_method)` if you want to clean up).

Comment: Good tip, thanks.  The main thing is that I can get the original behaviour back.  Since it's all just in-memory debugging it doesn't really have to be pretty, I guess.  Sort of :)

Comment: IIRC if you use the method method (or possibly method and then unbind) you can get a reference to the original without polluting any namespace.